# recommended tilt ratio for ibm jre

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

i have an application running on aix box with ibm jre (IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX))

In around 90 minutes, gc collection (with -Xgcpolicy:gencon) takes more than 12 minutes(with tilt ratio 80%) and happens every 3 to 5 minutes

I want to increase memory allocated (Xmx) so that gc time should stay below a minute.

Can i consider tilt ratio into consideration for increasing Xmx?
If yes, what is the recommended range of tilt ratio for application to work smoothly.

Comment: How are you specifying the tilt ratio? As per http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50%2Fdiag%2Funderstanding%2Fmm_gc_generational_tilt.html it looks like tilt ratio is adjusted automatically to maximize the time between GC invocations.

Comment: @Buchi I do not have any intention to change the tilt ratio, i know this is not allowed. What i need is **1.** Is there any correlation in `higher tilt ratio` and `gc collection time` . **2.** If Yes, how much java memory do i need to allocate to keep `gc collection time` under a minute.